# How to link app to a certain View Controller

Tags: swift2, xcode7, ios9, spotlight

I'm using the Spotlight API introduced with iOS 9 and I have my code all setup (I can search from spotlight) but it takes me to the default view controller. How can I make it load to a specific view controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you tap on the spotlight search result the delegate method in your app delegate file is called. Once you are in that method its upto you to display any view controller that you would want. Typically it should be a navigation controller so that the default "back" button is visible which would take you back to spotlight search when tapped.
Depending on which view controller you would want to show, wrap that with a navigation controller and present it to the user.